# Given a UL, how to remove all items after 5, if any?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery is there a way remove an LI items after position 6?

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

A way to dynamically remove items 6+ (6 & 7 in this case) and not break if there are less than 6 items? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just:

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/dpCsj/

PS: in your title you say "after 5" and "after 6" is in the question body. I've chosen the one from the title

Comment: @inhan: yep, depends on aims - selector could be different. The most important is `:gt()`

Answer (score 2):

Can be accomplished with an nth-child selector:

`$( 'ul li:nth-child( n + 6 )' ).remove( );`